# SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake (error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a SQL server version `12.0.6205` and the following code in a .Net Core 3.1 (or 6) Web Api controller:

```
 var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = DataSource,
    UserID = UserID,
    Password = Password,
    InitialCatalog = InitialCatalog,
    ApplicationIntent = ApplicationIntent.ReadWrite,
    
    // Same result if true/true
    Encrypt = false,
    TrustServerCertificate = false
};

var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = connection, CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[Table]" })
{
    connection.Open(); // Breaks here
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Console.WriteLine(reader.HasRows);
}
```

Locally this code works without issues but when executing in Azure's App service it breaks when opening the connection with:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
```

I also have been able to reproduce the error, locally, if creating
a docker imaged based on `appsvc/dotnetcore` (any tag)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/dotnetcore:3.1-latest_20220105.1

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80  

EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot/
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, please follow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137669/5772425

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like @DraggonDragger said this is a TLS issue but in my specific case I can't rely on the SQL server being updated to allow TLS 1.2 therefore I had to allow TLS 1.0 in the application.

I ended up following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61523341/17892120;

Essentially, for docker images, adding this line is enough:
`RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

And for Azure's App Service, we can add
`sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf && dotnet Test.dll` for the startup command.

For future reference, there's also a discussion about this in GitHub, [link](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633).

Comment: could you help look: https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/11249#issuecomment-1455376523

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I'm adding a TODO for my situation to migrate the database to a more modern windows server and sql server and then remove this openssl legacy workaround once that's done.

I'm concerned that Encrypt=false had no effect (even though it's not best practice to not encrypt this kind of traffic) since it is misleading, it's still trying to encrypt and fails miserably.

Answer (score 3):

```
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

to your Dockerfile right above the ENTRYPOINT

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633

Answer (score 1):

**Found a similar issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633) which is TLS HandShake Failure in SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake with Docker Image.**

Also, This error typically occurs in client environments like docker image containers, Unix clients, or Windows clients where TLS 1.2 is the minimum supported TLS protocol.

Install the latest updates on supported versions of SQL Server1 and ensure the TLS 1.2 protocol is enabled on the server.

1. Install the target SQL Server's TLS/SSL certificate in the client environment. It will be validated if encryption is needed.
2. Set the "Trust Server Certificate = true" property in the connection string.
3. Generate a new TLS/SSL Certificate for the server whose hash is signed with at-least the SHA-256 hashing algorithm.

**Reference: [Pre-Login Handshake Error Solution from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#login-phase-errors)**

Comment: the step is 3,1,2?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows and using Docker for SQL Server:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrongPassword' -p 1434:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

Ensure port mapping avoids conflicts with other services on Windows. Use a different external port (e.g., 1434) if necessary to avoid conflicts. Note that SSL port for SQL Server is 1433 by default. Connect SSMS using the mapped port and ensure TLS settings are configured accordingly.