# Azure app service can't connect to local db exposed via public IP

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a public mysql db that is exposed via an IP (dev server)

I would like to access it from my app .net core that is deployed as an azure web App

I am currently not able to do so.

I can access this DB from any PC I tried so far (so db is accessible for sure).

The Web app error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
```

Is there any configuration needed on the web app to access the db?

I added the connection string to the web-app config

I would tear the db down after using it

Comment: is your  database server locally hosted or in azure ?

Comment: it is hosted locally, I tried it on multiple external pc's and the db connection works. So it must be azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To connect your azure hosted app to your local hosted MySQL server you have to use a hybrid connection.
  Under the networking tab click on the hybrid connection:

[image]

After that click on the`add hybrid connection`and then click on the `create new hybrid connection`

[image]

[image]

After that fill this form to create a hybrid connection

[image]

To connect your local db to azure we would need a relay this relay would be a hybrid connection manager download this hybrid connection manager from the portal

[image]

After installing the hybrid connection manager, you will get ui something like this

[image]

Click on the add new hybrid connection

It will prompt you to login into you azure account

[image]

Select your subscriptions and then the available hybrid connection will appear.
Select the ones you want and save.
You are now connected to the azure app service.

If the hybrid connection manager is showing `not connected` then restart the computer, it will start connecting.

Answer (score 0):

You must havé to check your rules connexion and then maybe your firewall.

Best regards.