# .NET 8: SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake (error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

Tags: c#, openssl, .net-8.0

**Describe the bug**

Same issue [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652241/sql-server-pre-login-handshake-error-31-encryptionssl-tls-handshake-failed). We need to upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8, needed for LTS, however, we cannot upgrade the database (yet).

```
Stack trace:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: End of stream reached
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.ReadInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken token, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SyncReadWriteAdapter.ReadAsync(Stream stream, Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.EnableSsl(SNIHandle handle, UInt32 options)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at sqltest.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/src/ConsoleAppConnectivity/Program.cs:line 29
ClientConnectionId:d974cac0-f1a3-4864-9867-17360db6e502
```

**To reproduce**

Very simple console app to replicate:

```cs
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace sqltest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            try
            {
                var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "<host>",
                    UserID = "<user>",
                    Password = "<pw>",
                    InitialCatalog = "<DB>",
                    TrustServerCertificate = true,
                    Encrypt = false
                };                

                using SqlConnection connection = new(builder.ConnectionString);
                Console.WriteLine("\nQuery data example:");
                Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");

                connection.Open();

                var sql = "SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.<Table>";
                using SqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);
                using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nDone. Press enter.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
COPY certificates/ca/cert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as build
COPY certificates/ca/cert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /src
COPY . . 

RUN dotnet restore src/ConsoleAppConnectivity --ignore-failed-sources
RUN dotnet build src/ConsoleAppConnectivity/ConsoleAppConnectivity.csproj -c Release -o /app --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish src/ConsoleAppConnectivity/ConsoleAppConnectivity.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# Recommended change to make it work
RUN sed -i 's/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleAppConnectivity.dll"]
```

**Expected behaviour**

Top 10 records from `dbo.< Table >`

**Further technical details**

- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version: 5.1.2
- .NET target: 8
- SQL Server version: SQL Server 2012
- Operating system: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)

**Additional context**

I have tested with different .NET images, any of the .NET 8 works.
The same run changing .NET images and target framework to 5, 6 and 7 connects properly and works as expected.

I've run and made changes in the openssl.cnf in **"/etc/ssl/**" and "**/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf**" and looks like it does not contain the "SECLEVEL" and/or "MinProtocol" properties.

I have also appended the properties into the configuration files, but seems not difference take effect.

Here is the output once I open the file:

```
RUN cd /usr/lib/ssl/ && cat openssl.cnf
```

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# See doc/man5/config.pod for more info.
#
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests,
# but may be used for auto loading of providers

# Note that you can include other files from the main configuration
# file using the .include directive.
#.include filename

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .

 # Use this in order to automatically load providers.
openssl_conf = openssl_init

# Comment out the next line to ignore configuration errors
config_diagnostics = 1

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
# oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        =
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]
# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca', 'req' and 'ts'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

# Policies used by the TSA examples.
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7

# For FIPS
# Optionally include a file that is generated by the OpenSSL fipsinstall
# application. This file contains configuration data required by the OpenSSL
# fips provider. It contains a named section e.g. [fips_sect] which is
# referenced from the [provider_sect] below.
# Refer to the OpenSSL security policy for more information.
# .include fipsmodule.cnf

[openssl_init]
# providers = provider_sect

# List of providers to load
# [provider_sect]
# default = default_sect
# The fips section name should match the section name inside the
# included fipsmodule.cnf.
# fips = fips_sect

# If no providers are activated explicitly, the default one is activated implicitly.
# See man 7 OSSL_PROVIDER-default for more details.
#
# If you add a section explicitly activating any other provider(s), you most
# probably need to explicitly activate the default provider, otherwise it
# becomes unavailable in openssl.  As a consequence applications depending on
# OpenSSL may not work correctly which could lead to significant system
# problems including inability to remotely access the system.
# [default_sect]
# activate = 1


####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = ./demoCA      # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
#unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several certs with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                    # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extensions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extensions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options.
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString (PKIX recommendation before 2004)
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings (PKIX recommendation after 2004).
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: ancient versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings.
string_mask = utf8only

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# This is required for TSA certificates.
# extendedKeyUsage = critical,timeStamping

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer

basicConstraints = critical,CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo

####################################################################
[ tsa ]

default_tsa = tsa_config1   # the default TSA section

[ tsa_config1 ]

# These are used by the TSA reply generation only.
dir     = ./demoCA      # TSA root directory
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    # The current serial number (mandatory)
crypto_device   = builtin       # OpenSSL engine to use for signing
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  # The TSA signing certificate
                    # (optional)
certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   # Certificate chain to include in reply
                    # (optional)
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem # The TSA private key (optional)
signer_digest  = sha256         # Signing digest to use. (Optional)
default_policy  = tsa_policy1       # Policy if request did not specify it
                    # (optional)
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  # acceptable policies (optional)
digests     = sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512  # Acceptable message digests (mandatory)
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  # (optional)
clock_precision_digits  = 0 # number of digits after dot. (optional)
ordering        = yes   # Is ordering defined for timestamps?
                # (optional, default: no)
tsa_name        = yes   # Must the TSA name be included in the reply?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_chain   = no    # Must the ESS cert id chain be included?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_alg     = sha1  # algorithm to compute certificate
                # identifier (optional, default: sha1)

[insta] # CMP using Insta Demo CA
# Message transfer
server = pki.certificate.fi:8700
# proxy = # set this as far as needed, e.g., http://192.168.1.1:8080
# tls_use = 0
path = pkix/

# Server authentication
recipient = "/C=FI/O=Insta Demo/CN=Insta Demo CA" # or set srvcert or issuer
ignore_keyusage = 1 # potentially needed quirk
unprotected_errors = 1 # potentially needed quirk
extracertsout = insta.extracerts.pem

# Client authentication
ref = 3078 # user identification
secret = pass:insta # can be used for both client and server side

# Generic message options
cmd = ir # default operation, can be overridden on cmd line with, e.g., kur

# Certificate enrollment
subject = "/CN=openssl-cmp-test"
newkey = insta.priv.pem
out_trusted = apps/insta.ca.crt # does not include keyUsage digitalSignature
certout = insta.cert.pem

[pbm] # Password-based protection for Insta CA
# Server and client authentication
ref = $insta::ref # 3078
secret = $insta::secret # pass:insta

[signature] # Signature-based protection for Insta CA
# Server authentication
trusted = $insta::out_trusted # apps/insta.ca.crt

# Client authentication
secret = # disable PBM
key = $insta::newkey # insta.priv.pem
cert = $insta::certout # insta.cert.pem

[ir]
cmd = ir

[cr]
cmd = cr

[kur]
# Certificate update
cmd = kur
oldcert = $insta::certout # insta.cert.pem

[rr]
# Certificate revocation
cmd = rr
oldcert = $insta::certout # insta.cert.pem
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer help someone else:

dotnet8 base image uses Debian 12, which uses openssl-3, where SHA-1 was downgraded to security level 0, looks like SQL Server 2012 does not support TLS 1.3.

I have tested including the below lines at the end of the openssl.cnf and managed to connect it.

```
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

For more information follow [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2252)